# How does one obtain the formula for the number of genus one curves in P^2 using Getzler's relation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry

I am trying to get the formula for the number of degree $n$ genus one curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ passing through 3n generic points, by following the procedure in Getzler's paper

https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9612004.pdf

In particular, I am trying to obtain equation 0.1 (on page 2). I actually have been able to obtain the first two terms of the equation (the terms involving $N^1_i N^0_j N^0_k$ and also the term involving $N^1_i N^0_j$); however,  I have not been able to obtain the last term (the terms involving $N^0_i N^0_j$ and also the term involving $N^0_n$).

Let me first explain the basic setup/notation and then I will ask the concrete question where I am stuck (I believe I am making a mistake while intersecting certain cycles).

First of all, we denote $N^0_n$ to be the number of genus zero, degree $n$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ through $3n-1$ points and similarly $N^1_n$ 
is the number of genus one curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ through $3n$ points.

Let us first consider the space $\overline{M}_{1,4}$ and consider the rational (co)homology group $H^*(\overline{M}_{1,4}; \mathbb{Q})$. 
The main result of Getzler's paper is Theorem 1.8  (Page 8) where he proves an equality of cycles in $\overline{M}_{1,4}$. For convenience, let me write down that equality (in a slightly different way, by rearranging some of the terms on the right hand side)
$$ 2 \delta_{2,2} = \frac{2}{3} \delta_{2,3} + \frac{1}{3} \delta_{2,4} - \delta_{3,4} - \frac{\delta_{0,3}}{6} - \frac{\delta_{0,4}}{6} + \frac{\delta_{\beta}}{3}.$$ 
I will explain shortly what these cycles $\delta_{i,j}$ are (they are also explicitly described by the author in section 1, pages 3, 4 and 5).

Now, let us consider the moduli space of maps with a total of $3n+2$ marked points 
$$ \pi: \overline{M}_{1,4 + 3n-2}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) \longrightarrow \overline{M}_{1,4}$$

We can pull back these cycles $\delta_{i,j}$ in $\overline{M}_{1,4 + 3d-2}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$ and intersect with another apropriate cycle to get equality of numbers. I believe, how Getzler gets the final formula (equation 0.1) is by doing the following thing: let $D$ be the following cycle in $\overline{M}_{1,4 + 3d-2}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$

$$ D := ev_1^*{L_1}\cup \ldots \cup ev_4^*{L_4} \cup ev^*(p_1) \cup ev^*(p_2) \cup \ldots ev^*(p_{3d-2}).$$

Here $L_i$ denotes the class of a line, $p_i$ denotes the class of a point and $ev_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ evaluation map. What I believe one needs to do to get equation 0.1 is that you have to intersect the left hand side and the right hand side of the equation (the way I have written it above) with D. I have tried doing that and I manage to get the first two terms correctly.

Now, let me explain the precise step where I am stuck (I believe I am intersecting cycles incorrectly).

$\textbf{Question} 1$ Let us first concentrate on the cycles $\delta_{2,2}$, $\delta_{2,3}$, $\delta_{2,4}$ and $\delta_{3,4}$. 
Let me now start by explicitly describing $\delta_{2,4}$. This cycle corresponds to the domian where you have a torus, with a sphere attached and then a second sphere attached to the first sphere 
(if you draw a picture, it will be a torus, followed by a sphere, then another sphere). Furthermore, two of the points are on the first sphere 
and two of the points are in the second sphere.

Notice that there are $4$ choose $2$ ways of distributing the points on the domain (i.e. $6$ different ways).

Now consider $\pi^* \delta_{2,4}$. These will comprise of curves of degree 
$(d_1, d_2, d_3)$ such that $d_1+d_2 + d_3 = n$; on the torus it is degree $d_1$, and on the two spheres it is degree $d_2$ and $d_3$. Let us first assume $d_1 \neq 0$ and intersect the resulting cycle with $D$. We can do a similar thing with the remaining $\delta_{i,j}$. That indeed gives the first two terms of Getzler's formula.

Hence, let us now consider the case where $d_1 =0$ and $d_{2} =i$, $d_3 = j$ (and for now, lets us assume $i \neq 0$ and $j \neq 0$).

My question is this:  what is the intersection number

$$ \Big(\pi^*\delta_{2,4} \Big)\Big|_{(d_1 =0,  ~d_2 = i, ~d_3 =j)} \cdot D = ? $$

I think, one has to use the fact that the genus one, degree zero, one pointed GW invariant of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is $-\frac{1}{8}$ (that is basically Proposition 2.7 on page 11, and it also follows from the answer given in this mathoverflow post [Virtual fundamental class of Moduli space of stable maps in genus 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306373/virtual-fundamental-class-of-moduli-space-of-stable-maps-in-genus-1)).

However, I think it is likely that I am making a mistake while using that Proposition. I have a similar question with the other $\delta_{i,j}$, but I think if I figure out how to correctly calculate this specific intersection number, I will be able to figure out the rest.